# Scoped css not being applied with lang="scss"

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework

I'm using Quasar and trying to style `q-table` first column:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
td:first-child {
  background-color: #747480 !important;
}
</style>
```

However this does not work even after reloading/hot reloading/restarting server whatever.

Removing scoped works fine. I have no idea what is going on. Anyone could provide solution for this problem?

EDIT:
Here is working demo:

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-snyder-w345l?file=/src/pages/Index.vue)

Just remove scoped from the style and the color will change.

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to show the issue happening.

Comment: please share more code. What you are after probably though, is another selector - nothing to do with vue. And do you have a scss loader?

Comment: @BastianSpringer if it is another selector then why it works correctly when `scoped` is removed?

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have overlooked that sentence previously... Well, then I would believe that the td elements are not in this component (or a child component) but instead in another parent component. If you would share more code (maybe the whole template), or even better an example like @palaѕн said, we would be able to help better

Comment: Yes, a demo will really help to debug the code and provide more insight into the real issue here. Otherwise, you will keep getting answers based on assumptions which might or might not work.

Comment: @palaѕн I added the working demo in codesandbox that has this wierd bug

Comment: @BastianSpringer It also happens in the example in the codesandbox

Comment: @AlexT So I've just looked at it and unfortunately didn't find a non-hacky solution either. My hacky solution would be to import a stylesheet (or somehow apply styles anyway) and create the scope on your own. For example wrapping the table in a div with an id and then do #customstylescope td{background-color:#747480!important}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**: In Vue 3 the piercing selector is `:deep()`. e.g:

```scss
.qtable :deep(tbody td) {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

...will produce something along these lines:

```css
.qtable[data-v-f3f3eg9] tbody td {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

---

**Initial answer:**

**Warning on using: `>>>` with `lang="scss"`!**

While `>>>` seems to work as expected when `lang` is not specified (or when it's set to `css`), the same is not true with `lang="scss"`.

The only piercing selectors that work with `lang="scss"` (in latest 2.x Vue — `v2.6.11`) are **`/deep/`** and **`::v-deep`**.
What I know for sure is that it's not related to `node-sass` or `dart-sass` packages, as I tried with both and it behaves the same. So it's either at Vue package level or at `sass` package level. But I don't consider downgrading any of those to be a feasible solution

For some reason, `>>>` gets transformed into `> > >` when used in `scss` which, for obvious reasons, makes anything inside that code block no longer apply. What should happen is `>>>` should be removed and any parts of the selector after that point should no longer have the scoping attribute applied (as it does for the other 2 piercing selectors).

Note it used to work, and I have no idea when or why it stopped working (I've personally always preferred `::v-deep`, for no particular reason).

In your case: just wrap everything into `::v-deep {}`:

```html
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  ::v-deep {
    td:first-child {
      background-color: #747480; /* no need for !important */
    }
    .q-table tbody td {
      white-space: normal;
    }
  }
</style>
```

... and they'll apply.

Comment: Note: usage without arguments is deprecated since Vue 3.0.

Answer (score 3):

Use [deep selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors) in style scoped

In your code, add "id" in your q-table

```
<q-table
    title="Treats"
    :data="data"
    :columns="columns"
    row-key="name"
    dark
    color="amber"
    id="my-table"
        />
```

And then change your scoped style into like this one

```
<style scoped>
  #my-table >>> td:first-child {
    background-color: #1313eb !important;
  }

 .q-table tbody td {
    white-space: normal;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: `>>>` only works with `lang="css"` (which is default). Question is about `lang="scss"`. I've added an answer explaining in more detail.

Comment: you can use /deep/ or ::v-deep

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `<style scoped lang="scss">` (For example in Vue.js) deep selector `/deep/` required instead of `>>>` between parent and child tags for applying CSS parameter to all the children:

```
// Does not apply to all children and won't work:
.my-table .cell {
  word-break: keep-all;
}

// Apply it to all the children:
.my-table /deep/ .cell {
  word-break: keep-all;
}
```

`/deep/` or `::v-deep` is a replacement of `>>>` in Sass scoped pre-processor.